# Spring Boot JasperReport compileReport failed

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have moved a jasper process from former maven Spring project to a new Spring Boot project (with 2 maven modules).
It works nice with the old project but it fails with the new one.

The code is the same, the jrxml is the same, the dependencies are the same.

the error happens at compileReport declaration between the 2 logger lines :

```
try {
        logger.info("generatePDF method");
        final OutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
        JRRewindableDataSource dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource();
        if (list != null) {
            dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
        }
        
        final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(model);
        // JasperDesign design=JRXmlLoader.load(is);
        logger.info("model: " + model);
        final JasperReport compiledReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
        logger.info("compiledReport ok");
        if (compiledReport !=  null) {
            //Création du rapport final au format JasperReport
            final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledReport, parameters, dataSource);
            
            //Export au format pdf
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, result);
            
            return result;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("EditionService - generatePDF() method: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        return null;
    }
```

I can read the 1rst line ("model: xxx") in the log file but never the 2nd ("compiledReport ok").
But there is no exception catched (try catch blok). I don't unsertand why.

This process is in a loop and as it never ends, the process always restart...

Answer (score 1):

Founded !

In the stderr.log file (not in stdout) there was an error :

Digester class was not found. This is solution :

[I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615630/i-am-getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-digester-rule-er)